# Delete Row Where Cell Contains "V" Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA and have looked at a number of questions and answers on this but cannot see why my macro isn't working.  I have:

```
i = 1
For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    'test for v in column f and delete if there isn't one
    str = Cells(i, "F").Value
    If InStr(1, str, "V") <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print str
    Else
        Rows(i).Delete            
    End If
```

This prints out each str that contains V but doesn't delete the rows after the else.  What am I missing? I've tried Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete but that didn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing i and it's not correctly initialized it with your first row in the used rows range. So, in your case, it always stays at 1.

In many cases with a for-each loop you won't use an i counter, but sometimes you will.

Solution:
Replace `str = Cells(i, "F").Value` with `str = range(row.row, "F").Value`

Replace `Rows(i).Delete` with `row.Delete`

Lastly, you'll need a `next` at the end or you'll get a compile error. That will complete your for-each loop.

Comment: Thanks.  I did have the increment and Next on there but forgot to copy them over.  I'm bit confused about when you need the i counter and when you don't in the for loops and am just using trial and error (more errors than trial at this point) to try and figure it out.